# Putting random numbers randomly into 2d array

Tags: java, random, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array, and I've set all the cells to a enum type State.SAFE. Now I want to place, lets say 5, of those cells, randomly to State.HIT. So I have:

```
Random objrandom = new Random();

State[][] playField = new State[5][5];
int w;

for (w = 0; w < 5; w++) {                  // set all states to SAFE first
    int h = 0;
    playField[w][h] = State.SAFE;

    for (h = 0; h < 5; h++) {
        playField[w][h] = State.SAFE;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {           // try and set 5 states, randomly, to HIT
    playField[objrandom.nextInt(5)][objrandom.nextInt(5)] = State.HIT;
}
```

The problem is every time I run it, all the cells are either still in SAFE state or the Hit states are distributed non randomly, i.e the first row of every column or there are more than 5 HIT states.

Comment: What is the type of `objrandom`? Is it an instance of `Random` class? If yes, how do you initialize it?

Comment: Yes its a 5x5 array, I mean there are 25 array elements so that is 5x5? The random class is initialized: Random objrandom = new Random();

Comment: @BarneyGorilla Can you show a complete code example? It should work fine based on what you have posted so the issue may be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you need exactly 5 cells to be set to HIT you can't use random like that because you may get the same number more than once. This is how I would do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  State[][] playField = new State[5][5];

  setStateToSafe(playField);
  List<Integer> hits = getRandomIndices(5);
  applyHitStateToIndices(hits, playField);

  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(playField));
}

private static void setStateToSafe(State[][] playField) {
  for (int w = 0; w < playField.length; w++) {
    Arrays.fill(playField[w], State.SAFE);
  }
}
private static List<Integer> getRandomIndices(int n) {
  List<Integer> hits = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) hits.add(i);
  Collections.shuffle(hits);
  return hits.subList(0, n);
}
private static void applyHitStateToIndices(List<Integer> hits, State[][] playField) {
  for (int i = 0; i < hits.size(); i++) {
    int hitIndex = hits.get(i);
    int row = hitIndex / playField.length;
    int column = hitIndex % playField.length;
    playField[row][column] = State.HIT;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for you detailed reply. Although setting the playField to a certain size and putting random HIT states in it is already supposed to be part of an existing method, a method to initially setup the board game for the user, so I can't create other methods inside it. Also I don't really understand your last two methods sorry, I'm new to programming. Filling the array with the SAFE state looks like a better option though, thanks.

Comment: @BarneyGorilla You can't *put* a method within another method, but you can *call* a method from another method. I just separated each action in its own method to makes things clearer. In the end, a better design would be to create a `PlayField` class and place all that logic in the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your solution, since the line `playField[objrandom.nextInt(5)][objrandom.nextInt(5)]=...` might result in the same cell being references twice. I can't be sure if this is the cause of your problem, but it might be at least part of it.

If you wanted to fix that, you'd have to check each random number against the history of already changed cells, and request for a different random in case of double hits.

What I suggest is a completely different approach. Instead of requesting the indices of the row and column of the cell in which to change the value, the random should represent the probability that the values will change.

In other words:

- Go over all the cells in the array, generate a random value between 0 and 1 (using `nextDouble()`)
- If the value is below the probability that this cell should change (5 cells out of 25 means 5/25 = 0.2 probability = 20%), if so, set the value to `State.HIT`, otherwise set it to `State.SAFE`

The code should look something like this:

```
Random objrandom = new Random();

State[][] playField = new State[5][5];

for (int w = 0; w < 5; w++) {             
    for (int h = 0; h < 5; h++) {
        playField[w][h] = (objrandom.nextDouble() < 0.2d) ? State.HIT : State.SAFE;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not guarantee that exactly 5 cells will be set to HIT.

Comment: The only two references to the number 5 in your post are: `lets say 5, of those cells` and `or there are more than 5 HIT states`, which I understood as: `there should be about 5 cells but no more`. You can clearly see that my solution answers those requirements. You should edit you question and rephrase the requirements since they are inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

If the small overhead doesn't cause much trouble, then you could do something like this:

Create a class for representing a point on your field.

```
final class Point {
    public final int x;
    public final int y;

    public Point(final int x, final int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Fill a list with all the possible points, and shuffle it.

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        points.add(new Point(x, y));
    }
}
Collections.shuffle(points);
```

Now the first `N` (5 in your case) points will be randomized, and 100% not the same.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Point p = points.get(i);
    playField[p.x][p.y] = State.HIT;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an idea. Maybe I should try allocating random numbers using something other than a for loop. Thanks

Comment: If you do `shuffle` your list of points, then the order of your points will be randomized. So for example `[(0,1), (0,2), (0,3)] -> [(0,2), (0,3), (0,1)]` Then if you iterate on these points, you can access these points as they were randomly generated, because they are ordered randomly.